# window.replaceState in iframe causes parent window scroll jump?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, html5-history

In Google Chrome & Safari, with a parent page containing an `iframe`:

```
<html>
    <title>Parent</title>
    <body style="font-size:90px;">
        <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Integer posuere erat a ante venenatis dapibus posuere velit aliquet.</p>

        <p>Integer posuere erat a ante venenatis dapibus posuere velit aliquet. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit.</p>

        <iframe src="frame1.html" frameborder="0"></iframe>

        <p>Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ornare vel eu leo. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum.</p>

        <p>Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

If the iframe uses `window.replaceState` with a hash:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Frame</title>
        <script>
        window.onload = function() {
            window.history.replaceState(null, null, '#')
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body style="background-color:purple;font-size:20px;"></body>
</html>
```

...on window load, the parent window will jump to the scroll position of the iframe:

[image: iframe bug demo]

Everything I've read about `window.replaceState` suggests that it shouldn't maniuplate the parent frame at all.  Am I missing something?